# Having trouble with EPSON Stylus SX130 scanner

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, scanner

I am trying to scan files with an EPSON Stylus SX130 on windows 7 x64.

When i plug in the printer, windows automatically find drivers for printing, but not for scanning.

So i go to the [manufacturer website to download the drivers](http://www.epson.co.uk/Store/Printers-and-All-in-Ones/Epson-Stylus-SX130/Drivers-Support?defaultOSId=3&target=#), select `windows 7 64-bit` and download drivers for `EPSON Scan`.

The install works fine, but when i try to scan a file (eg: from paint or Windows fax and scan), the folowing message pops up and freezes the application : the progress bar plays the animation forever and the application does not respond.

[image: popup message]

I then have no choice to kill the application with the task manager.
Do you have an idea of what's going on ? How can i fix the problem, ie: how do i get the scanner actually **scan files without freezing** ?

---

I tried to install the driver from the CD given in the printer package, and got the same problem.

The only help i found so far (the error seems somewhat related) is [this](http://www.cableforum.co.uk/board/19/33655504-epson-scanner-problem.html) :

> Install a xp virtual machine and run it in there

Answer (score 1):

The "[Epson Scan](http://www.epson.co.uk/Store/Printers-and-All-in-Ones/Epson-Stylus-SX130/Drivers-Support?target=driver&languageId=1&driverId=328206&defaultOSId=22&DRV_CATEGORY_CODE=DRV)" at Epson's site is the scanning interface software (TWAIN interface), not the actual driver for the scanner.  The actual driver is also offered there, it's titled as "[Driver](http://www.epson.co.uk/Store/Printers-and-All-in-Ones/Epson-Stylus-SX130/Drivers-Support?target=driver&languageId=1&driverId=328203&defaultOSId=22&DRV_CATEGORY_CODE=DRV)".

You may want to try using that driver instead of the one Windows found automatically.